# Change format of Datetime column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a datetime column in a SQL table. This column is storing the information in MM.DD.YYYY HHMMss format. However, I want that the column accepts date in DD.MM.YYYY format. I want to do this change in the table-column properties and not through code.
So how to change (alter) the datetime format?

Comment: The *internal storage* for a DateTime is always the same. You need to apply formatting using `CONVERT` (or `FORMAT` in SS2014) while inserting/selecting.

Comment: you can check the link : [cast and convert (Transact-SQL)] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: I am using this statement on my table `INSERT INTO tableName (created,lastsync) VALUES ('16.07.2012 08:36:20','01.09.2015 18:55:08')` However, this is resulting in an error saying "_The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value_."

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The column is not storing the Information in MM.DD.YYYY but as an Timestamp.It may just Display as Datetime. So, if you want to fetch the Datetime in Specific Format you need to use use Convert (Transact-SQL)